# How do I remove spaces in between my output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
cost = input("Enter the expenses: ")
cost = cost.split()
total = sum([int(i) for i in cost])
print("Total: $",total)
```

This is the output:

```
Enter the expenses: 5 6 89 5
Total: $ 105
```

I just need help to remove the space after the $ sign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print("Total: $" + str(total))
```

Comment: Thank you so much..I didn't know this. Will keep in mind for the future. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it from [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print) , you can use `sep` argument. Example -

```
print("Total: $",total,sep='')
```

By default (if no `sep` parameter is specified) Python uses `' '` (space) as sep, to separate each different argument to `print()` function , and that is why you get a space inbetween your `$` and `total` . Using above method we change that to an empty strig.

Demo -

```
>>> total = 123
>>> print("Total: $",total,sep='')
Total: $123
```

---

Or you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) that would give you more control on formatting your output. Example -

```
print("Total: ${}".format(total))
```

Comment: Thank You!! this helped too

Comment: Probably worth pointing out that by default python separates comma separated values with that space, and by passing `sep=''` you're overwriting the default parameter to remove it.

Comment: Thank you for that @AnandSKumar